# Getting “gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion ‘GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)’ failed” when running GTKmm program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, gtkmm, gdk

I try to run program uses GTKmm library on Lubuntu 16.04 over x11vnc. When I start it in terminal, it throws to errors:

```
(process:6981): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:6981): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried debugging the code, but the segmentation fault occurs before the first line of `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered a similar problem. Spent two days before I could resolve it. The problem lies in some **unallocated pointer**. I may be able to provide better help if you post your code here.
However, here are some probable reasons:
1. You used a reference to an object, as a data member of your `Gtk::Window` class. You may want to use a pointer instead, and initialise it with a memory in your constructor.
2. One of your functions was supposed to return a pointer to an object but it did not return it. In which, case the caller may get a null pointer.